# docker pull - connection refused - Alpine Linux behind proxy

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux, http-proxy

My real machine is deployed with Alpine Linux, My problem is how to pull docker images using pull command when machine is behind a corporate proxy. I search internet for how pull images when docker host machine is behind a proxy and reached [docker official documentation which demonstrate that process but on Ubuntu Linux](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy)

even I found here [(StackOverflow) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130899/cant-docker-pull-connection-refused) talks about the same issue but also on Ubuntu linux, my question how to do so on Alpine Linux.
help will be appreciated.

Comment: Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28093517/5226835

Comment: No, Above two links use Ubuntu Linux with systemd, Alpine Linux uses OpenRC

Comment: Did you try to set `http-proxy` and `https-proxy`?

Comment: Where to set them in Alpine Linux for docker service?