# Unable to build docker Image, connection refused

Tags: docker, http-status-code-403, docker-build

I am trying to build my first Docker Image and am encountering the error below.

For what its worth I also tried to access the urls via curl and got similar results.  Not sure what I am missing.

Do I need some type of credentials to pull in the main image?

```
$ docker build -t springio/gs-spring-boot-docker .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp 44.207.51.64:443: connect: connection refused
```

```
$ curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Comment: Are you in an environment where there's some sort of proxy compromising the integrity of HTTPS connections?

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes I am in a environment that requires a proxy, I have run export http_proxy=<myHttpProxy> and export http_proxy=<myHttpsProxy> on the cli before running docker build.  I have also added them in the docker config.json file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer solved part of my problem:
[Can't docker pull - connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130899/cant-docker-pull-connection-refused)

After that I also needed to get .docker.io white listed for my proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to reboot docker deamon and try to run build again?

Can you just pull this image?

```
docker pull openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
```

Comment: Have not tried to restart deamon, I am not familiar with how to do that.  That pull gets similar results. docker pull openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp 44.207.51.64:443: connect: connection refused

Comment: Where do you use Docker? I mean the operating system.

Comment: I am trying to build on ubuntu. I just tried shutdown -r now, afterwards I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you try to pull other images? For example: `docker pull ubuntu`
If you face the same issue, it can be download rate limit https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/